# What is the IntelliJ shortcut to change the import for a class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If you've imported the class from the wrong package, is there a shortcut to change the import for a class? I would like to get the same pop-up as when you've not imported any class yet and you press ALT+ENTER.

Now I just go to the import statement (is there a shortcut for that?) and delete it in order to get the pop-up I mentioned above.

Comment: What you can do it, remove the variable/line which imported the class, then use Alt+Shift+O to organize the import which will remove unused imports.
Now you can add the code again and press ALT+ENTER to get that popup

Comment: There isn't any dedicated action for this. This can be implemented as a plugin.

Comment: A simple Google search leads me to here; just struggling with classes with same name in distinct packages, no solution. Would be a huge plus.